# Why working dipping in mouseenter/mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Wrote for example handlers `mouseenter / mouseleave` in react, and to my surprise e.target return child elements.

Created [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLYLoM) on js, and there everything perfectly works, only on the parent.
This handlers dont must work with child elements and dont bubbled, so why its happening?

Component code

and [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLaYLK?editors=0010)

```js
class MovieItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      popup: false
    };
  }

  outItem = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log(e.target)

    e.target.style.opacity = 0
    // this.setState({
    //     popup: true
    // });

  };

  leaveItem = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log(e.target)
    e.target.style.opacity = 1
    this.setState({
      popup: false
    });

  };


  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "movie-item"
      id = {
        this.props.id
      }
      onMouseEnter = {
        (e) => this.outItem(e)
      }
      onMouseLeave = {
        (e) => this.leaveItem(e)
      } >

      <
      div className = "movie-item__data" >

      <
      div className = "movie-item__poster" >
      <
      img src = "http://lorempixel.com/140/205/"
      alt = "" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "movie-item__title" > title < /div>

      <
      /div> <
      /div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events):

> The `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events propagate from the element being left to the one being entered instead of ordinary bubbling and do not have a capture phase.

Comment: Thanks, you know how its stop?